# How to send text messages with java using AppleScript and Terminal?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, applescript, runtime

I'm trying to learn how to use java to send terminal commands. I want java to send a terminal command that runs an AppleScript file that takes in two parameters (a phone number, and a msg). I think the problem is I don't know how to format a command with parameters.

```
public void sendMsg(String phoneNumber) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        String newWord = list.remove(0);
        String[] command = {"osascript", 
        "sendmsg.scpt "+phoneNumber+" "   +"\""+newWord+"\""};

        try {
            runtime.exec(command);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This program sends each word in the array "list" to the phoneNumber. The command doesn't work though. The AppleScript code works when I directly enter the parameters on to terminal.

The terminal command that works is: (file is in my home directory /~)

```
osascript sendmsg.scpt 1234567890 "Hello"
```

Basically, looking for the java equivalent of the python command:

os.system("command");

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class TestCmdLine {
    
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        
        String[] cmd = {"/usr/bin/open", "-a" , "osascript.app sendmsg.scpt 1234567890 \"Hello\" "};
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        
    }
}
```